# Installing plugins on installation/activation

Tags: plugin-development

Is it possible to install extra plugins on certain plugin installation/activation?
I tried to install them using:

```
$upgrader = new Plugin_Upgrader(); 
$upgrader->install(...)
```

But it's not working. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, post more details. What is `Plugin_Updater`? See [ask].

Comment: There is nothing worse than plugins relying on other plugins and/or forcing things upon the user. Why not just merge them into a single plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though its slightly [complicated by this bug](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20241), which I discuss on [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27850/deactivate-plugin-upon-deactivation-of-another-plugin) (original: http://stephenharris.info/deactivate-other-plug-ins-on-deactivation/) They actually handle deactivating, rather than activating, but the principles are the same.

*At time of writing that [trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20241) has a patch committed for 3.7.*

The following should activate 'B' when 'A' is activated:

```
//This all goes inside Plugin A.

//When A is activated. Activate B.
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'my_plugin_A_activate'); 
function my_plugin_A_activate(){
    $dependent = 'B/B.php';
    if( !is_plugin_active( $dependent ) ){
         add_action('update_option_active_plugins', 'my_activate_dependent_B');
    }
}

function my_activate_dependent_B(){
    $dependent = 'B/B.php';
    activate_plugins( $dependent );
}
```